# How would I navigate this kind of XML structure using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Basically, I have a file similar to the example below (albeit much larger).

What I need to do is effectively ask someone a question, and then depending on their answer, navigate to a part of the XML. For Example..

Would you like Food or Drink? (Answer, Drink)
Which Drink would you like? Coke, Beer, Fruit Juice (Answer, Fruit Juice)
Which Fruit Juice? Orange, Apple, Pineapple?

I've used XML files plenty in C# before, but not in this way, and was wondering if it's possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
  <Questions>
      <Start>Would you like Food or Drink?</Start>
       <Food>
           <WhatFood>What Food</WhatFood>
      </Food>
      <Drink>
              <Coke>Coke
                <Answer>Coke</Answer>
              </Coke>
              <Beer>Beer
                <Answer>Beer</Answer>
             </Beer>
             <Juice>Beer
                <OrangeJuice>
                <Answer>OrangeJuice</Answer>
                </OrangeJuice>
                <AppleJuice>
                   <Answer>AppleJuice</Answer>
                </AppleJuice>
                <Pineapple>
                   <Answer>Pineapple</Answer>
                </Pineapple>
             </Juice>
      </Drink>
  </Questions>
</Company>
```

Comment: Seems like at each step in the hierarchy, you need to access the direct child node that matches the answer to the question in the current node. For example, at step <Drink> and asking "Which drink would you like?", you would enumerate the child nodes of <Drink> and get the one whose tag name matches the given answer: <Juice>.
It also makes sense for each node that represents a question to hold an additional sub-element <Question> with the text specified in it.

Comment: Since the "possible" answers are always the same.  I would parse all the data from posted ml and then check the actual answer against the possible answers.  Otherwise, you will be parsing the same xml multiple times which is less efficient than parsing once.